Firestore onDocumentWritten Trigger Not Firing on Document Writing in Cloud Functions with node
I am building a Firebase project where I need to run a cloud function whenever a document is created in a specific Firestore collection. I'm using Node.js with the Firebase Admin SDK and have set up Firebase functions. Everything else is working correctly, but I can't get the function to trigger upon document creation at a specific Firestore path
Here's my code:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccount.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

exports.testFunction = functions.firestore
    .onDocumentWritten("Test/{docId}", (change, context) => {
        /* ... */
        console.log('Written to Test');
    });

When I add a new document to the Test collection, the testFunction does not get triggered as expected. I intended for this function to execute and log "Written to Test" each time a document is created in this path.
Could anyone help me understand why this trigger isn't firing and suggest how I might fix this?

How did you determine that the testFunction does not get triggered? You might want to have a look at the documentation on writing and viewing logs from Cloud Functions, as console.log is not supported without an extra import.

I wrote a document in the Test collection via both the firebase console and a client application and nothing is being shown on my console.
I also want to clearify that this is a nodejs appication I created to host myself. It is not from the firebase emulator. I'm thinking the firestore triggers (onDocumentWritten, onDocumentCreated) only work with firebase cloud fuctions emulator or thier console.

Yeah, that won't work. When you run the script in your question with just Node.js it won't do anything. You need to run it in an environment that can execute the Cloud Function hat you define in there, so either the production Cloud Functions environment on Google Cloud or in the Firebase emulator for Cloud Functions.

You said in the comments that you're running the code you shared as a plain Node.js script, which won't work. Node.js looks for top-level code to execute, so it just runs the admin.initializeApp({...}) and then does nothing else.
To get the onDocumentWritten to execute and respond to changes in Firestore,, you need to run it in an environment that can execute the Cloud Function. So this can either be the production Cloud Functions environment on Google Cloud or the Firebase emulator for Cloud Functions.

Isn't it possible to implement the same logic in a node js application to be hosted on my own server?

If you want to run it on your own server, you don't need to use Cloud Functions. Just use the quickstart and code samples for Node.js in the regular Firestore documentation.

The admin sdk is working fine on my server but the issue is that I want to listen to document changes in firestore and I don't know how to implement it. I wanted to use the document snapshot changes but I feel like it will consume a lot of memory
